# Android ListView setSelection() does not seem to work

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListActivity` that implements `onListItemClick()` and calls a `doSomething()` function of the class. The latter contains `l.setSelection(position)` where `l` is the `ListView` object.

Now there is a `onClickListener()` listening for a button click that perfoms some actions and that too calls `doSomething()`.

In the first case, the selected item get positioned appropriately, but in the latter, nothing happens.

Any clues about this strange behaviour and how I might make it work?

Answer (score 107):

maybe you need to use function:

```
ListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean checked);
```

Comment: This should be the answer to the question. Ensure that the listview is set to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE in the layout XML or in the java via: `myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` and the `setItemChecked` worked for me, it moved the selection indicator to the item I passed in (unselecting the previous one).

Comment: `ListView.setItemChecked()` is not scrolling to the specified position.

Answer (score 68):

use `requestFocusFromTouch()` before calling `setSelection()` method

Comment: ｓｈｏｕｌｄｎｔ　ｂｅ　requestFocusFromTouch() ａｆｔｅｒ　calling setSelection()？

Comment: @pierr Reading JavaDoc of `requestFocusFromTouch()` I think the order proposed by AlexD is right.

Comment: It didn't. it causes bad effect in the UI. release and getting the focus back hides the suggestion from the keyboard and u need to click again to get it back.

Comment: This worked for me, but the ListView item highlights as if the user was holding their finger down on the specified ListView item and as soon as I touch the screen the item is no longer selected (highlighted). Any solutions so that the selection is set by a finger tap and not a hold?

Answer (score 39):

I know this is an old question but I just had a similar problem that I solved in this way:

```
mListView.clearFocus();
mListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mListView.setSelection(index);
    }
});
```

Comment: Good answer - fixed my problem in a very non-hacky way where most of the others didn't. Vote this up!

Comment: I was missing mListView.clearFocus(); Thanks man! Someone Make THIS the answer

Comment: This is NOT working 100% because the "clear focus", it is working because enough time have elapsed so the webview finished rendering. Put a bigger HTML content and you'll see.

Comment: Why to add delay in selection

Comment: This is useful for Listview inside Dialog.

Comment: in my case listview.post(()->listview.setSelection(index)) were enough

Answer (score 17):

You might need to wrap `setSelection()` in a `post`ed `Runnable` ([reference](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/127ca57414035301#msg_27db6f1b808e1506)).

Answer (score 13):

`setSelection()` does not necessarily have visual impact. The selection bar only appears if you use the D-pad/trackball to navigate the list. If you tap on the screen to click something, the selection bar appears briefly and vanishes.

Hence, `setSelection()` will only have a visual impact if the activity is not in touch mode (i.e., the last thing the user did was use the D-pad/trackball).

I am not 100% certain this explains your phenomenon given the description you provided, but I figured it is worth a shot...

Comment: However, the docs state for setSelection(): "If in touch mode, the item will not be selected but it will still be positioned appropriately". And that's what driving me crazy! Could always be a bug though.

Answer (score 6):

If you use an Adapter for your ListView add this code to your adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends
        ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, null);
        } else {
            rowView = (View) convertView;
        }

        //...

        // set selected item
        LinearLayout ActiveItem = (LinearLayout) rowView;
        if (position == selectedItem)
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);

            // for focus on it
            int top = (ActiveItem == null) ? 0 : ActiveItem.getTop();
            ((ListView) parent).setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
        }
        else
        {
            ActiveItem
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border02);
        }

    }

    private int selectedItem;

    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }

}
```

In your Activity:

```
myAdapter.setSelectedItem(1);
```

Comment: There is a semantic error with ActiveItem.  In the if(position==selectedItem) block, you call it's member function setBackgroundResource, and then in the next line check to see if it is null. Also, is it b/c the root viewgroup of R.layout.my_adapter a LinearLayout the reason for the cast ?

Comment: This looks like a pretty bad hack.

Answer (score 4):

For me calling

```
listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

and then

```
 listView.setSelection(position);
```

solved the issue.

if you do that in a runnable it works without calling requestFocusFromTouch(), but the old position of the ListView is showen for a sekound.

Comment: I think you mean adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: For prevent show old pos if you use `Runnable`, call `setSelection` twice: one before post `Runnable` and second in `Runnable`.

Answer (score 4):

I have an very large Request with Webcontent. When I used the code in onCreateView the Listview wasnt even finished loading.
I put it in onPostExecute of my AsyncTask.

```
            //Get last position in listview
        if (listView != null && scrollPosition != 0) {
            listView.clearFocus();
            listView.requestFocusFromTouch();
            listView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    listView.setItemChecked(scrollPosition, true);
                    listView.setSelection(scrollPosition);
                }
            });
        }
```

Dont forget to set the item checked in on Click ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use the smoothScrollToPosition(int position) method of ListView

Comment: For me `setSelection(int)` not worked if user change ListView size by keyboard in <19 API, but this `smoothScrollToPosition(int)` works, but looks like workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can try 2 ways like these:
Solution A:

```
    mListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (null != mListView) {
                mListView.clearFocus();
                mListView.requestFocusFromTouch();
                mListView.setSelection(0);
            }
        }
    });
```

In some complicated situation, this solution will bring some new problems in Android 8.x.
 Besides it may cause unexpected onFocusChange().

Solution B:
Define a custom view extends ListView. Override method handleDataChanged().Then setSelection(0). In CustomListView:

```
@Override
protected void handleDataChanged() {
    super.handleDataChanged();
    if (null != mHandleDataChangedListener){
        mHandleDataChangedListener.onChanged();
    }
}
HandleDataChangedListener mHandleDataChangedListener;

public void setHandleDataChangedListener(HandleDataChangedListener handleDataChangedListener) {
    this.mHandleDataChangedListener = handleDataChangedListener;
}

public interface HandleDataChangedListener{
    void onChanged();
}
```

In activity:

```
    mListView.setHandleDataChangedListener(new CustomListView.HandleDataChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            mListView.setHandleDataChangedListener(null);
            mListView.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Ok, That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case smoothScrollToPosition(int position) worked, can you also tell me how to set that scrolled position into center of the list. It appeared at the bottom of visible items.

Comment: you could do parent_width/2 and subtract it from the scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to set
`ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` or `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`
then
`ListView.setSelection(position)` or `ListView.setItemChecked(position, true);`
works fine

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in my case. I am not using a Runnable since my class is extending ListFragment. What I had to do is make my index a final;
final index = 5;
mListView.setSelection(index);

Answer (score 0):

I found that sometimes setSelection will not work because I set attribute "android:height" of listView to "wrap_content".

And the times my App won't work is that when listView become scrollable from non-scrollable.

For example, if my app is "File Browser App". When my list is less than, let's say 6, then it's non-scrollable. Now I return to the parent directory, and it has 11 objects, and I want to set selection to some position, and it won't work here.

```
to\from    |    Scrollable  | non-Scrollable
```

Scrollable   |        O      |        O( of course )

non-Scrollable  |        X      |      O( of course )

I don't want to use post(Runnable), because there will has delay.

==================================

Answer:

You can try to set "android:height" to "match_parent"

God, it spends three days.

Comment: Hi, does it also have any effect with using layout weight ?

Answer (score 0):

When use post to `setSelection()`, the `ListView` will see first , then scroll to the position , thank to "**魏經軒**", then layout actually will effect the `setSelection()`, because `setSelection()` call the `setSelectionFromTop(int position, int y)`, there is another way to solve it.

```
listView.setAdapter(listView.getAdapter());
listView.setSelection(123);
```

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K ,  I am not used to use editor to format my coding.Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution to this problem was:

```
listView.clearChoices();
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply try this code

```
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  listView.setSelection(position);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```