# How to move the ListView as page up function on Android?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Now I can do the page down with the following code.

```
listView.setSelection(listView.getLastVisiblePosition());
```

But when I want to move up to the first visible positon, there is no way to do as page up.
Because after moving to the first visible position, I will never know which item should be moved to.
I only can move to the upper-one item but not like a page moving.

Or is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work)?

Comment: Vikas, the setSelection() do works. But when you move to the first visible item, you never know how many items to move up to because upper items are not being draw or layouted yet.