# Go to a item in Listview without using smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, list, listview, scroll, selection

I'd like to go to (display) a specific item in my listview but without scrolling. I don't want any animation but I'd like to be instantaneously transported to the desired item.

I'm using a checkable listview : `mylistview.setChoiceMode(1)` .

I understood that `mylistview.setSelection(position)` is the solution, but when I use it, nothing happens (maybe because it's a checkable listview ?).

When I use `mylistview.smoothScrollToPosition(position)`, it works well but I have obviously this scroll animation which I don't want.

What could I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a similar question, maybe it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work

Comment: Thank you for answering. I think I'll go with antew' solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this out:

```
    myListView.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            myListView.setSelection(pos);
            View v = myListView.getChildAt(pos);
            if (v != null) 
            {
                v.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
```

From this Google Developer list answer by Romain Guy [Link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6741)

Comment: This is an OK solution but it doesn't behave at all like `smoothScrollToPosition()` (not talking about the animation of scroll, but the way the listview go to the displayed item, because it make the selected item always be first and so the listview always "jumps" to display this item first which looks wierd). But I think I'll be able to deal with it and it seems that this is the quickest solution anyway. I hope that they'll correct this issue. Thanks for your answer.