# android listview make an item visible without using scroll

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with 150+ items, I need to make one visible from code. I currently use smoothscrolltoposition but when the desired item is far away from the current visible item it takes several seconds to arrive.

Is there anyway to simply get rid of the smooth scrolling and simply make the item visible directly?

Thanks,
Ignacio

Comment: This might help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889732/go-to-a-item-in-listview-without-using-smoothscrolltoposition

Comment: Hope that you are using viewholder. At times, recyclerview is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use postdelayed for smooth scroll

```
 listview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

//  smoothscrolltoposition 
                        }
                    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

After several testing and reading the thread suggested by audi , I got this solution:

Strangely, the trick is in reassign the adapter to the listview, not even it is needed to recreate it, just reassign.

```
            listView.Adapter = adapter;
            listView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
            listView.SetSelection(index);
            adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```