# Focus on last item of list view

Tags: android, listview, onscroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android ListView setSelection() does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work)

On scrolling a list view, when end of list is reached I am fetching other batch of data, after fetching is done, I want focus on last item of list view before scrolling. `setSelection()` is not working. Can anyone suggest me better option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(android.R.layout.your_item_layout, null);
        }

        //your specific code here

        if (position == mList.size()-1){
            //fetch other batch of data
        }

        return view;
    }
```

getView method will be called before getting visible on the screen because of the preloading. But I think, this is what you are looking for.