# Highlighting row in listview that uses arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-view

I have created a custom lisview with images and text by using an array adapter. I would like to highlight one of the row manually, but I cannot seem to do this. I have tried using `setItemChecked` and `setSelection(1);`. I have made sure to disable touch events by calling `listView.setEnabled(false);`, as I read that manual selection might not work if touch events are enabled. Any insight into this matter would be greatly appreciated. I have included my source code below.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    // GUI
    int Update_Frequency = 1000;
    double ack = 0;


// Sensor Constants
public static String temperature = "--";
public static String humidity = "--";
public static String lpg = "--";
public static String alcohol = "--";



// Layout
ListView listView;
ItemAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Initialize Interface
    Model.LoadModel();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    String[] ids = new String[Model.Items.size()];
    for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    {ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);}
    this.adapter = new ItemAdapter(this,R.layout.row, ids);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listView.setEnabled(false);
    listView.setItemChecked(1, true);
    listView.setSelection(1);



    Model.LoadModel();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    GUI_Management();

}   

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.action_connect:
            break;
        case R.id.action_disconnect:
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            break;
        case R.id.action_about:
            break;
        case R.id.action_exit:
            break;
        default:
            break;
  }

  return true;
}


private void GUI_Management()
{
    new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //Replace with a changeable variable
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            Model.LoadModel();
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(Update_Frequency);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

}
```

**Array Adapter**

```
public class Model extends MainActivity
{
    public static ArrayList<Item> Items;

    public static void LoadModel() 
    {
        Items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        Items.add(new Item(1, "temperature_icon.png", "Temperature/Humidity               " + temperature + "°F / " + humidity + "%"));
        Items.add(new Item(2, "gas_icon.png", "LPG                                                   " + lpg +" ppm"));
        Items.add(new Item(3, "alcohol_icon.png", "Alcohol                                             " + alcohol + " ppm"));
    }  

    public static Item GetbyId(int id)
    {
        for(Item item : Items) 
        {
            if (item.Id == id) 
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    } 
}

class Item 
{
    public int Id;
    public String IconFile;
    public String Name;

    public Item(int id, String iconFile, String name)
    {
        Id = id;
        IconFile = iconFile;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] Ids;
    private final int rowResourceId;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.Ids = objects;
        this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
        String imageFile = Model.GetbyId(id).IconFile;

        textView.setText(Model.GetbyId(id).Name);
        // get input stream
        InputStream ims = null;
        try {
            ims = context.getAssets().open(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // load image as Drawable
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null);
        // set image to ImageView
        imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
        return rowView;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

put setonclick listener in rootview object which are inflate by you in getview method this will solve your issue and on click event you can change the background of rootview and many more you can do with it.

```
    @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            int id = Integer.parseInt(Ids[position]);
            String imageFile = Model.GetbyId(id).IconFile;

            textView.setText(Model.GetbyId(id).Name);

        if (position == selectedItem)
        {
            rootView /*or you can use any viewgroup*/
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_dark_blue);


        }
        else
        {
            rootView
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border02);
        }

                return rowView;    
        }
   private int selectedItem;
    public void setSelectedItem(int position) {
        selectedItem = position;
    }
```

i know this is not good solutionbut might this help you out you can use setSelectedItem method to highlight row 
and please use static placeholder class for efficiency and use position field in static placeholder class to get position of selected row

Comment: Okay but how do I do this manually. I don't want to highlight a row when it is clicked, but rather I want to automatically highlight a row from within the code. Any ideas?

Comment: oh sorry for my misunderstanding but you have to highlight all row in listview then you have to view this link and assign background to your root view .
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Okay thanks. just out of curiosity, is there a reason my approach above doesnt work? because I have seen that method implemented with standard listviews. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work

you get the ans from above link

Comment: I tried all of the solutions in that post and I still cannot seem to highlight a row. Looking at my code, do you have any idea why this is?