# ListView.setSelection is not working properly

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have the code below. I created a `FloatActionButton` to take pictures of all items in the `ListView`, but I need the screen to update to take them all. The `list.setSelection` is working, but is working after the `while` ends.

For example: I have a ListView that contains 6 images, the code bellow is taking pictures of the first three twice, and then update the screen to the last 3.

```
{

    ListView list = JMainFragment.getInstance().getList();

    list.setSelection(0);
    int j = 0;
    while (j < list.getCount()) {
        int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLastVisiblePosition() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++) {
            if (list.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) {
                JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(i), "operadora" + j + ".png");
                j++;
            }
        }
        list.setSelection(lastPosition);
        list.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `list.invalidateViews();` after  `list.setSelection(lastPosition);`?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? It seems similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446373/android-listview-setselection-does-not-seem-to-work